# How can I make this function loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, timer

```
function argsToArray(args) {
  var r = []; for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    r.push(args[i]);
  return r;
}

argsToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(function(img) {
  img.src = img.src.split('VTlibOlte8YCb').join('X0X810D0' + Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));;
});
```

I tried adding setInterval(argsToArray,500); at the end but that seem to have broken things.

This is quite archaic and will probably crash the browser, but for this experiment it might just work.

```
function reloadPage()
  {
  location.reload();
  }

  setInterval(reloadPage,.5);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Why and what do you want to loop ?

Comment: might seem stupid, but i'm grabbin an bas64 img src and screwing with it by adding the random math replacement. I just want that to loop...

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to change the elements you are iterating over with foreach. Try putting the changed elements into a new array or list.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume from using native `forEach` that you're targeting IE9+, so instead of manually pushing the collection contents into an array you could just:

   ```
   function argsToArray(args) {
       return Array.prototype.slice.call(args)
   }
   ```
2. The rest of the code looks perfectly workable, maybe there's something wrong with the `split()` or `join()` arguments. Please explain what are you trying to achieve here.
3. Adding `setInterval(argsToArray,500)` would just call your first function without any arguments, you should use an anonymous function or pass arguments into the setInterval/setTimeout function (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval#Callback_arguments)).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do something like this?

```
window.onload=function() {
  var imgs = document.images;
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
      var img = imgs[i];
      var val = 'X0X810D0' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1);  
      img.src = img.src.replace(/VTlibOlte8YCb/g,val);
    }
  },1000);
}
```

which is designed replace the src of each image every second - but actually only once since there is no more VTlibOlte8YCb to replace after the first time

Here is one that does replace the value each time

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/E8Mdf/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var imgs = document.images;
  var oldVal = new RegExp(/VTlibOlte8YCb/g);  
  var val = 'X0X810D0' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1);  
  var tId = setInterval(function() {
    for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
      var img = imgs[i];
      val = 'X0X810D0' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1);  
      img.src = img.src.replace(oldVal,val);
      oldVal = new RegExp("/"+val+"/g");  
    }
  },200);
}
```

Comment: That is what I want, but that didn't seem to do it. Here's a JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/47S38/

Comment: I had a typo. See new code and demo (which does not seem to do a LOT)